# Reading EOF as a char in C

Tags: c, eof, getchar

I know it might sound stupid but how can I exit this loop ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
        printf("%c", c);
    }while(c != EOF);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm reading a book and trying to do the following exercise:
"Verify that the expression getchar() != EOF is 0 or 1"
If I read the value of EOF stored in an integer value it will be equal to -1 but if I try to catch a -1 as a char is mindfuck. From what I've understood EOF is a value which is not assigned to any other char ..

anyone can help ?

edit1:
I know that c should be an Integer ... I'm reading it as a char intentionally.

edit2:

```
int main(){
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%d\n", c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

----->

```
int main(){
    int c;
    int i = 0;
    char str[2];
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        str[i] = c;
        ++i;
        if(i > 1) i = 0;
        if(str[0]=='-'&&str[1]=='1')
        {
            c = EOF; // doens't exit loop
        }
        else printf("%d\n", c);


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why I can't understand this.

Comment: `getchar()` returns an `int` so you should change `char c` to `int c`. It's also a good idea to check that it's not `EOF` _before_ printing it. `int c; while((c = getchar()) != EOF) { printf("%c", c); }` - or `for(int c; (c = getchar()) != EOF;) { printf("%c", c); }`

Comment: Yes, `EOF` is a value which is not equal to any character.  So, by definition, it will not "fit" into a variable of type `char`.  If you try to jam it into a `char`-sized slot (like a variable `char c;`), some of the bits will get scraped off, and it will (wrongly) compare equal to some character value — perhaps ÿ — when the whole point was that it *not* compare equal to any character value.

Comment: Beginner's traps are thinking that "character" means `char` and that "number" means *integer*. Note that it's OK to pass an `int` to `%c` format spec (for `printf`, but not the `char*` pointer for `scanf`). When you pass a `char` (to a variadic function) it is promoted to `int` anyway.

Comment: If type `char` is one byte of 8 bits — as it is on the vast majority of machines today — then it can hold 256 different character values.  But `EOF` is a *257th* value.

Comment: @SteveSummit: The C standard does not require that `EOF` have a value different from any `char` value. It is a nice idea, but it is not essential. A C implementation could support text files with no “character” have a code the same value as EOF (e.g., 255 supported characters, including the null terminator) while binary files are used with functions for which `EOF` is not needed. There was discussion years ago on Stack Overflow about whether a C implementation with `sizeof (int) == sizeof (char)` could conform to the standard, and this was part of it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well, yes, I remember those discussions too (back on Usenet), and having `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)` is, to use the OP's wording, a mindfuck. :-)  (But yes, I know it has existed, on Crays and elsewhere.)

Comment: @SteveSummit: Actually, in common C implementations, [`EOF` does have a `char` value](https://godbolt.org/z/jPsvWMcqj). Recall that `getchar` returns either `EOF` or a character value as an `unsigned char`, not a `char`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'd put it [like this](https://www.c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html).  (An update is imminent, and I shall certainly have to add a footnote about those poor systems with int-sized chars.)

Comment: @drain_ *I'm reading it as a char intentionally.* But why?  That way lies madness!  And if you're on a system where type `char` is unsigned by default, this will explicitly prevent you from ever verifying that `getchar() != EOF` can yield 0, because it never will.

Comment: (char) -1 what does this mean ? How can I read a string as a char ? How does the system know when for example that no more chars are available in a file ? I want to write  a value somehow that resembles that,,,, and allows me to exit the loop.

Comment: @drain_ you can read string char by char. When there is nothing to read system will signal it using EOF.

Comment: _"How can I read a string as a char"_ - You can read character by character as `int`- but store each in a `char` (until you read `EOF`, then you stop).

Comment: There are few (if any) standard C functions that either return a single character, or take a single character argument as `char`. They use `int`. Even this literal `'A'` is of type `int` which you can confirm with `printf("%zu", sizeof 'A');`

Comment: Re “if I try to catch a -1 as a char”: Are you trying to read a character with value −1? When you type `-1`, it is read as two characters, a hyphen and a digit. To get a character with value −1, you would have to type a special key sequence. (Easiest way might be to write a program that prints a −1 character to the display, then copy and paste that, if that works on the system you are using.) However, your `getchar` will return that as 255, but then storing it in a `char` will commonly yield −1.

Comment: @drain_ In an edit you added, *Why I cant understand dis*.  I suspect you're getting stuck somewhere between characters and the integer values that represent them, or more likely between the integers that represent characters and the very different, off-to-the-side integer that marks EOF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might help you to understand what's going on if you change the program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
        printf("%d\n", c);
    } while(c != EOF);
}
```

You'll notice that I have:

1. declared `c` as `int`
2. printed it using `%d`

If I run this program and type "abc" and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd>, this is what I see:

```
97
98
99
10
-1
```

97, 98, and 99 are the ASCII codes for `a`, `b`, and `c`.  10 is the code for newline, aka `\n`.  And then that -1 is the EOF that resulted when I typed <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd>.  (If you're on Windows, you'd use <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> and another <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead.)

In this program, although `c` is an `int` variable, that does *not* mean that it does not hold characters!  In C, characters are represented by small integers which are their codes in the machine's character set.  Here's a modification to demonstrate this:

```
int c;
int nch = 0;
char string[100];
do {
    c = getchar();
    printf("%d", c)
    if(c >= 32 && c < 127) {
        printf(" = '%c'", c);
        string[nch++] = c;
    }
    printf("\n");
} while(c != EOF);
string[nch] = '\0';
printf("You typed \"%s\"\n", string);
```

Now it prints

```
97 = 'a'
98 = 'b'
99 = 'c'
10
-1
You typed "abc"
```

There's no problem calling

```
printf(" = '%c'", c);
```

even though `c` is an int and `%c` is for printing characters.
There's no problem assigning

```
string[nch++] = c;
```

even though `c` is an int and `string` is an array of characters.

Comment: Is there any chance that i can add that -1 to rappresent a sequence of 2 chars like "-1" so that I can exit the loop by entering 2 chars in a row ? or is it possibile to "overload"somehow the EOF value with a new value.

Comment: @drain_ It's starting to become unclear what you are really trying to do. Why not use it like everyone else uses it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry, lost your fancy keycaps while fleshing out the answer.  Feel free to reinsert.

Comment: @drain_ Yes, you could write code to exit the loop on a specific two-character combination.  It would be unusual and (to my mind) not particularly useful.  `EOF` is a *very* general-purpose mechanism, and it will work properly when a program's input is redirected to read from a file (meaning that no one is typing control-D or control-Z).

Comment: "There's no problem assigning `string[nch++] = c;` [...]." No problem for the characters you entered. If `c > CHAR_MAX` then the conversion of `c` to a `char` value *could* be a problem (but not for typical implementations). EDIT: That won't be the case here because you are checking `c` has a reasonable value before assigning `string[nch++] = c;`.

Comment: @drain_ no, it is not possible to "'overload'" the EOF value with a new value.  When you're using `getchar`, EOF is a very specific marker that EOF has occurred.  It's defined by the system; it's not something you can change.

Comment: @drain_ The value of the character capital-A in ASCII is 65.  I hope you're not imagining that the value of control-D is -1.  The way that control-D (or control-Z on Windows) eventually gets mapped through to EOF as returned by `getchar` is rather elaborate.  I might have time to explain it later.  I really do wonder why you want to use something other than control-D/control-Z for keyboard end-of-file.  Really, everybody else finds them quite adequate.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how things work.

Comment: @drain_ See the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73706596/reading-eof-as-a-char-in-c/73708163#73708163) I just posted.

Answer (score 5):

1. `c` has to be `int` not `char`. It is especially important in implementations where `char` is unsigned. `-1` is represented by 0xffffffff (32 bit integer, twos complement) and assigned to char as 0xff. When compared 0xff will always be not equal `-1`. Thats why you should use `int` not `char`.
2. Test for EOF before printing. More suitable is `while(...) {}` loop

```
int main(){
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6sqa98bnq

Here you have an example what will happen if `c` is `char` and `char` is unsigned:
https://godbolt.org/z/bjfGv56z3

[image]

Comment: this code does the exact thing like the other one with char does... even if you insert -1 -->  program doesn't exit.

Comment: @drain_ no https://godbolt.org/z/WjWxYvs3T. There is a very important difference between those two.

Answer (score 4):

`getchar()` returns an `int` in the [`0` ... `UCHAR_MAX`] range or `EOF`.

To well distinguish these typical 257 different values, save in an `int`.

If saved in a `char` that is *signed*, an `EOF` with a typical value of -1 is saved yet so is some character, perhaps with the value of 255.  The loops then ends under one of 2 conditions.

If saved in a `char` that is *unsigned*, an `EOF` with a typical value of -1 is save as 255 and never equates to `EOF` resulting in an infinite loop.

Do the right thing.  Save in an `int`.

Compare before printing, else when `EOF` is returned it may print the same as if the character with 255 was read.

```
// char c;
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)) {
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

---

> From what I've understood EOF is a value which is not assigned to any other char

This is not quite true.  `EOF` is negative and characters (not *char*) are read with `unsigned char` values.

`EOF` may be -1 and a `char`, when *signed*, can also have the value of -1.  The key is to consider charters best originally as unsigned values, even when surprisingly saved in a *signed* `char`.

Deeper: It is an *old* C historic compromise that `char` is *signed* or *unsigned*.  Still, *character* processing best done as-if characters are treated as `unsigned char`.   This affects `getchar()`, `is...()`, `strcmp()` and other functions.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C Standard (7.21 Input/output <stdio.h>)

> **EOF**
>
> which expands to an integer constant expression, with type int and a
> negative value, that is returned by several functions to indicate
> end-of-file, that is, no more input from a stream;

As you can see there is nothing said what negative value the constant expression has.

However usually it is equal to -1.

The condition of the do-while statement

```
}while(c != EOF);
```

will be correctly evaluate to `1` and `0` if the type `char` behaves as the type `signed char`.  In this case the object `c` of the type `char` will be implicitly converted to the type `int` in the condition due to the integer promotions. That is the integer value `-1` stored in the object `c` of the type `char` will promoted to the type `int` and keep its value `-1`.

However depending on compiler options the type `char` can behave as the type `unsigned char`. In this case after this assignment

```
c = getchar()
```

the variable `c` will have an unsigned value. For example if it was assigned with `EOF` that is equal to `-1` then the variable `c` will have the positive value `255` that it will keep after the integer promotions.
As a result the condition

```
}while(c != EOF);
```

will always evaluate to `1` because `-1` is not equal to `255`.

So you should always declare the variable `c` as having the type `int`. In this case your code will not depend on how the type `char` behaves: either as `signed char` or as `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 2):

In an addendum to your question, you tried to have your loop exit when the user typed "-1", and you wondered why that didn't work.  You made one or two mistakes.  Here is a corrected version which you can try:

```
int c;
int i = 0;
char str[20];
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    str[i] = c;
    ++i;
    if(str[0]=='-' && str[1]=='1')
    {
        break;        /* fix here: was "c = EOF" */
    }
    else printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

Your code actually did recognize "-1", but in response it set `c` to `EOF`, but this accomplished nothing, because the next thing that happened was another call to `c = getchar()` in the `while` header at the top of the loop.

In the modified version I'm calling `break` when "-1" is seen, and this works.

Note that to exit the loop you must type the two characters "-" and "1", and you must type them at the beginning of the line.

Note that you're reading *characters* here.  The two characters "-" and "1" are *not* being treated as the integer -1, or as the C `EOF` value.  They're just two characters.  If you changed the `if` statement to

```
if(str[0]=='x' && str[1]=='y')
```

you'd end up with a loop that stopped when the user typed "xy" at the beginning of a line.

Comment: I do understand this... i know what the condition implies... what I am trying to say is : how does the system know that i've ended a file ? why it doesn't work if the value is -1 and why EOF can have more values and yet the system knows what's happening ... something to read would be fine as well .. i need to understand this

Comment: @drain_ Are you using Unix, Linux, MacOS, Windows, or something else?

Comment: I asked only because I'm tired of saying "control D (or control-Z on Windows)" all the time.  For now I'll assume you're using a Unix-like OS.

Comment: When you call `getchar`, it gives you the next character in the `stdin` buffer.  If the buffer is empty, the stdio code tries to refill it, typically by calling [`read`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read).  If `read` returns <= 0, that means end-of-file or error, so `getchar` returns the non-character value EOF.

Comment: So what causes `read` to return 0?  If you're reading from a file, `read` returns 0 when there are no more characters in the file.  If you're reading from the keyboard, `read` returns 0 if the user types control-D.  There's special code in the terminal driver to handle this.  Normally, if you type some characters, those characters get returned in `read`'s buffer, and `read` returns a value greater than 0.  But if you type that one special keystroke control-D, `read` returns 0 instead.  (Actually it's more complicated than that, but this gives the basic idea.)

Comment: Ok Steve I think I've got the concept behind it. Thank you.